# Ubuntu, Youtube doesn't work in Firefox 57

Tags: firefox, 17.10, youtube, html5

I have one computer with Linux Mint and Firefox 57.
I have two computers with Ubuntu Mate and Firefox 57.
In Mint I can watch YouTube videos in Firefox.
In Ubuntu I can not watch YouTube videos in Firefox.

I have searched for weeks but haven't found any solution that will fix this, so I'm trying my luck here.
Is there a way to make Firefox understand HTML5 in Ubuntu?

Comment: The problem is not HTML5. Probably graphics drivers.

Comment: I don't find that likely since it works in Chrome and I would assume that both Firefox and Chrome use the same graphics driver. Besides, it used to work in earlier versions of Firefox. But, you're right, the problem is not HTML5. It's Firefox.

Comment: What is the result from https://www.youtube.com/html5 ?

Comment: Everything is marked as supported on all three computers.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I have installed all gstreamer-ugly codecs. It used to work, but when Firefox 57 came it stopped working in Ubuntu and kept working in Mint.